# Creation event of simple struct is not emitted

Tags: rust, substrate, polkadot-js

I have a simple struct in a custom pallet:

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, RuntimeDebug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Kitty(pub [u8; 16]);
```

I am able to create a new `Kitty` from polkadot.js web app and check that the `KittyCreated` event is emitted looking at the network explorer:

```
/// A kitty is created. \[owner, kitty_id, kitty\]
KittyCreated(AccountId, u32, Kitty)
```

However when I modify the `Kitty` struct to have an additional `u32` param the object is created but the event is **not** emitted:

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, RuntimeDebug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Kitty(pub [u8; 16], pub u32);
```

If I check in Developer ChainState and query for the account Kitties I get:

```
kitties.kitties: Option<Kitty>
<unknown>
```

It looks like there is an issue with the struct, do you know what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my bad, had to add:

```
  "Kitty": "([u8; 16], u32)",
   ....
   }
```

to Settings.Developer

Comment: Yes, it is important to add your custom types for seeing every part interfacing properly.
Here https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.extend covers more in depth this topic